# Finding if a number is the sum of 2 powers

Tags: ruby, arrays, exponent

I successfully solved a problem where I'd determine whether or not a number could be written as a sum of two squares.

```
25 => [5,0], [3,4]
5**2+ 0**2 = 25 and 3**2 + 4**2 = 25
```

Here is how I solved that

```
def power_pairs(num)
  a = (0..100).to_a
  a.combination(2).select{|x|(x[0] ** 2) + (x[1] ** 2) == num}
end

power_pairs(40)
=> [[2,6]]
```

I want to modify this method to determine if the number passed in is actually a power number.

A power number can be represented as a sum of 2 powers.

```
27 = 0**2 + 3**3
28 = 1**2 + 3**3
```

How would I fix that method

Comment: You have stated your goal, but what's your problem? You clearly have a good understanding of how to solve this kind of thing to have been able to solve the initial problem. What is that is preventing you from figuring this out yourself?

Comment: Your code works and you want to know how to change it. Stack Exchange is for debugging/fixing coding problems... eeehhh... this is really bordering on a question that should be asked on [codereview.se] where you can ask "what's the best way to do...."

Comment: Do you want to restrict it to non-negative numbers? (Please, "yes".) E.g., if the number is `8`, is `4**2 + (-2)***3` permitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumptions**

I have assumed that, given an integer `n >= 8`, you want to determine if there are integers `a, p, b, q`, all `>= 2`, such that:

```
n = a**p + b**q
```

**Code**

Here is one way to do that. Note that I am caching values in order to perform multiplication rather than exponentiation (though one should test that to see if it actually saves time, or exhausts available memory).

```
def sum_power(n) # n >= 2
  @cache = (2..n-1).each_with_object({}) { |i,h| h[[i,2]] = i*i }
  (2..Float::INFINITY).each do |pow|
    (2..n-4).each do |m|
      x = m_to_pow(m,pow)
      if x <= n-4
        pow_other = power(n-x)
        return [[m,pow], pow_other] if pow_other
      else
        return nil if m == 2
        break
      end
    end
  end
end

def power(n) # n >= 2
  (2..Float::INFINITY).each do |pow|
    (2..n-1).each do |m|
      x = m_to_pow(m, pow)
      case x <=> n
      when 0 then return m, pow
      when 1
        return nil if m == 2
        break
      end
    end
  end
end

def m_to_pow(m,pow)
  x = @cache[[m,pow]]
  if x.nil?
    x = m * @cache[[m,pow-1]]
    @cache[[m,pow]] = x 
  end
  x
end
```

**Examples**

```
sum_power(25)                #=> [[3, 2], [4, 2]]     => 3**2 + 4**2
sum_power(26)                #=> nil
sum_power(3468)              #=> [[7, 3], [5, 5]]     => 7**3 + 5**5 
sum_power(1426716)           #=> [[19, 3], [17, 5]]   => 19**3 + 17**5
```

Answer (score 1):

The following gives an answer to divide a number to the sum of two numbers of equal power. It can be modified to solve your problem. You just need to modify `powers`.

```
def powers power, num
  a = []
  i = 0
  while (k = i ** power) <= num
    a.push([i, k])
    i += 1
  end
  a
end

powers(3, 100)
# => [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 8], [3, 27], [4, 64]]

def power_pairs power, num
  a = powers(power, num)
  a.map{|i, k| [i, a.find{|_, l| l == num - k}.to_a.first]}
  .select(&:last)
  .map(&:sort)
  .uniq
end

power_pairs(2, 25)
# => [[0, 5], [3, 4]]

power_pairs(3, 28)
# => [[1, 3]]
```